# Capybara/HTML - Check text in row below

Tags: html, cucumber, capybara

I'm struggling with capybara and content I wish to validate on a website.
The site is written in HTML.
I'm trying to verify text in a textbox based on its label value.
It's been a few hours now and I'm still stuck.. Hopefully someone can help me out!

The table structure basically looks like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td class="labelColumn"><span title="Label1:">Label1:</span></td>    
         <td class="outputColumn"><span id="Value1:" title="Value1:">Value1</span></td>
         <td class="labelColumn"><span title="Label2:">Label2:</span></td>    
         <td class="outputColumn"><span id="Value2:" title="Value2:">Value2</span></td>
         <td class="labelColumn"><span title="Label3:">Label3:</span></td>    
         <td class="outputColumn"><span id="Value3:" title="Value3:">Value3</span></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

What I am trying to do is to get **Value1** based on the content of **Label1**, get **Value2** based on **Label2**, etc.

I've tried things like:

> page.find(:css, 'tr', text: Label, :match => :first).should have_text(Value)

But that only meant it was searching within the **tr** as a whole, not specifically **Label1** with **Value1**

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: Should I be looking at DataTables?

```
| Label1 | Value1 |
| Label2 | Value2 |
| Label3 | Value3 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS selectors are not good for the structure you're trying to evaluate, but XPath will work well for it.  Something like the following should work

```
page.find(:xpath, ".//td[contains(., 'Label1:')]/following-sibling::td[1]/span").should have_text('Value1')
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response. I'm going to try this first thing tomorrow and get back to you! :)

Comment: Hi, just checked your method this morning, and the 'following-sibling' is a real eye-opener. Thanks for that! Unfortunately I found out that my html isn't as straight-forward as my example above... But I've gotten a good leap closer to reaching my goal. Thanks again!